# Asp.Net 5 Semantic Versioning

Tags: c#, asp.net, versioning, dnx, semantic-versioning

It seems that versioning works differently than in previous versions of .Net. The project.json seems to use semantic versioning (from what I have seen online) with the format Major.Minor.Patch-Special.

1. Does this replace the Assembly version idea or add to it? Or does it just get used with Nuget.
2. How does one access the version during runtime. I came across Nuget.SemanticVersion object online in the Microsoft.Framework.Runtime package but I can't find out how to retrieve it in code.
3. Is there a programmatic way to update this value on a build or just custom scripts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't say that versioning has changed in a particularly dramatic way. In a version number x.y.z, the "x" means "big changes / breaking changes," the "y" means "minor additions and fixes," and the "z" means "very minor fixes." That's pretty close to what Semantic Versioning (SemVer) states.

In a `project.json`-based project, there is only one place to specify the version, and that's in the `project.json` file itself. That one version is a SemVer (e.g. `x.y.z-prerel`) and is used for the NuGet package version *and* the assembly version, *and* the assembly informational version. If you've explicitly set the assembly version or informational version in the assembly, those will be respected and not overridden. (You can see the code [here](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/blob/bfc4776207bc08c3b2787fd04ae5c66960c7ed6a/src/Microsoft.Dnx.Compilation.CSharp/RoslynCompiler.cs#L255).)

At runtime you can read the assembly version through reflection (just like you always could).

When running in a DNX application there's also an [`ILibraryManager`](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/blob/c762978f184cc4ccd5a79c50b23a4aa1edae76b6/src/Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Abstractions/ILibraryManager.cs) interface that you can use to inspect the running application. However, that's a fairly advanced scenario.

Lastly, in the `project.json` file you can hard-code the x.y.z part of the version, e.g. `1.2.3` but you can also specify a `*` for the pre-release specifier, e.g. `1.2.3-*`. If you use `*` for the pre-release specifier, you can set an environment variable named `DNX_BUILD_VERSION` to specify the value of the `*`, e.g. `beta1` or `rc2-54289`.

There are some feature requests logged to allow more flexibility in specifying the entire version number externally.